# Symfony - Creating or Editing a form depending on the button pressed

Tags: symfony

I am creating a form which when saved, updates the current and any related entities (simple!) when I edit that, I have two buttons, **'Update Existing Version'** or **'Create New Version'**

If I click on create new version it basically needs to create everything within the form as a brand new version (a copy of the existing one but with a version integer increased by one) whereas if I click update its happy to just update the existing entity.

In Symfony the form is created with `$this->createForm(<class>, <data>)` and if I pass a new class entity to data then it'll create a new one and if I pass in an existing entity it will update.

However, I don't know until after I've handled the request whether the form is for a new version or to update current version as it comes from the button, which means the form is already created and initialized.

If it is a new version I also need to somehow update all of the related entities to the new version.

I think this should be relatively simple and I'm missing something obvious.

I'm using Symfony form collection to generate the form.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Kevin

Comment: To create a new entry in your table because of a "new MyEntity" and for an update you must retrieve your object in the database via doctrine or other so at some point you must probably pass it in the url in post an "id" then you retrieve your entity and you updated me your object in your database.
https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony-forms/easy-edit-form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case people come across this.

I simply checked within the form processing for which button was pressed, then just cloned the entity.

I then created a __clone function within the entity that dealt with the relationships it had (basically looped through the related entities, cloned them and changed the parent to $this).

That was it, everything else worked as normal